# Upload files to multiple folders using FTP

Tags: file, ftp, directory

I would like to upload some files into multiple folders on a single FTP account at once. I was looking all over on how to do this and couldn't find a solution. Is there an FTP client that will perform this feature?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Here is a tutorial that I figured out after going through the [docs](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/scripting):

1. Download and install [WinSCP](https://winscp.net/eng/index.php) and run it
2. Connect to Server
3. Go to Menu >Session >Server/Protocol Information
4. Copy the "[Server host key](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/scripting#hostkey) fingerprint" (`ssh-rsa 2048 xx:xx:xx:xx..."`)

Now create a file named `upload.txt`, add the following content (and modify as needed):

```
# Connect
open sftp://user:password@example.com/ -hostkey="ssh-rsa 2048 xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx..."
# Change remote directory
cd /home/user/public
# Download file to the local directory d:
get robots.txt d:\
# Upload file to current working directory
put d:\examplefile.txt 
# Disconnect
close
# Exit WinSCP
exit
```

Next create a batch file `run.bat` with the right paths:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\WinSCP\WinSCP.com" /ini=nul /script="C:\folder-with-uploadfile\upload.txt"
pause
```

Run the batch file.

Check if the exampe file robots.txt was downloaded to folder D: and if examplefile.txt is in the example folder on the server.

In case of multiple servers: https://winscp.net/eng/docs/script_upload_multiple_servers

PS: I am a long-time user of FileZilla, but by Feb 2018 they do not have this feature yet. So +1 for WinSCP.

Answer (score 0):

This feature isn't built into any client that I know of, or even the FTP protocol for that matter.

One client that mimics this is [Cyberduck](http://cyberduck.ch/) with it's "Synchronize" feature, allowing any changes on the folders you sync to be uploaded to the FTP server using timestamps.

Answer (score 0):

You can use any FTP client that supports directory synchronization.

WinSCP for instance:
https://winscp.net/eng/docs/task_synchronize

*(I'm the author of WinSCP)*